# File Stream in Flex Web App

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, filestream

I want to read a file that is in the client machine in **flex web app**.But ı dont want file to send server for processing ı want to to read content of file and show in it a component .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option for you is using [`FileReference.load()` method](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load%28%29).

Comment: And what? :) Read carefully: [`Runtime Versions: Flash Player 10, AIR 1.5`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#load%28%29).

Comment: An example to the load method: http://sherifabdou.com/2008/06/using-the-new-filereference-class-in-flex-to-save-and-load-without-a-server/